# Set image position on ProgressBar using ProgressBar scale - Android Studio

Tags: android, progress-bar

I would like to display a ProgressBar with an interval on it in my app. For example if the max value of the ProgressBar is 100, I would like to show an interval 60-80 symbolized by two vertical bars on the ProgressBar: one at 60, the other one at 80.

Is it possible to do it ? And if it is, how can I do it ?

Comment: check [this](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2826) and [this](https://codeforandroid.wordpress.com/2015/02/09/android-sample-code/) library

Comment: Rangebar: https://github.com/oli107/material-range-bar or https://code.google.com/p/range-seek-bar/